# Monodis under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mono, monodevelop, disassembly

I'm using Windows 7 and I need a tool to disassemble .dll file. After some search I understood that I can do it with monodis, but I can't find it on my laptop in spite of the fact that I installed MonoDevelop.
Does monodis come with MonoDevelop or do I have to install it like an addon? I spent about hour, trying to find out what am I doing wrong, but I still have no idea.

Comment: You have ildasm.exe available on Windows, no need for monodis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monodis comes with the mono framework http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html, maybe you run monodevelop with the microsoft  framework, but you don't have the mono framework installed.

if you have the mono framewok you can use monodis, from a command prompt, the path from monodis is

c:\Windows\Program files(x86)\Mono-2.10.8\bin

there is a option in the menu "Mono 2.10.8 for Windows", similar to the "Visual studio tools command prompt", the  "Mono-2.10.8 Command Prompt" opens a command prompt window setting the path to the executables, then you can use monodis.

I hope this could help you.